# Node + Heroku: Cannot connect to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am pretty new to all `mongoDB`, `node`, and `heroku`, and had an app that functioned completely locally, and then I attempted to deploy to heroku, and while successful, I cannot connect to my database.

I've followed several tutorials, installed the mongolab add-on in heroku, but no database functionality is working.

I attempt to connect to my database in my `app.js` with the following:

```
var uristring = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/EDGE';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
    }
});
```

...but I never see an error message or a success message, its almost like when my app launches, my `app.js` file never fires.  I've followed the [Thinkster IO MEAN stack tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#creating-schemas-with-mongoose) when setting up my app, but perhaps in production, something isn't being called.. any thoughts would be helpful